# How do i keep track of letters used in hangman game in c++?

Tags: c++

i am trying to make a game of hangman in c++ and i can't seem to keep track of the letters that have already been used in the game. I have included the code below so you can check it out and please let me know how to solve this problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){

string words[] =
{   "artistic",
    "recreational",
    "programmer",
    "indistinct",
    "sincere",
    "pulchritude",
    "legendary",
    "scientific",
    "oblivious",
    "tomorrow"
};


string word,unknownword,wordrevelation;
   char playername[100];
   string usedletters;
   int wordlength,numwrongofguesses,i,w;
   char letter,playagain;
   bool letterfound;

   cout << "Please enter your name: ";
   cin.getline(playername,100,'\n');
   cout << endl << endl;
   cout << "OKAY " << playername << " HERE WE GO!!!!!!!!!";
   cout << endl << endl << endl;

srand(time(0));
w=rand()%10;
word=words[w];

wordrevelation=word;
wordlength=word.size();

for(i=0;i<wordlength;i++){
    unknownword[i]=word[i];
    word[i]='-';
}
cout << "OKAY HERES THE HIDDEN WORD "<< word << " AND IT IS " << wordlength << " LETTERS LONG" << endl << endl << endl;


numwrongofguesses=8;
int count=0;
int counter=0;
int x;
bool Gameover=false;
while(!Gameover){
   while (1){
   cout << "ENTER A LETTER " << playername << " : ";
   cin >> letter;
   for (x =0;x<counter;x++){
        if (usedletters[x] ==letter){
            cout << "Already used." << endl;
   x=27;
   break;
   }
   }if(x==27)
   continue;
   break;
   } usedletters[counter]=letter;
    counter++;

   letterfound=false;
    for(i=0;i<wordlength;i++){
        if(unknownword[i]==letter){
            letterfound=true;
            word[i]=letter;
            count++;
        }
    }


    cout << endl << endl;

    if(letterfound==true){
        word[i]=letter;
        cout << "THE LETTER " << letter << " EXISTS IN THE WORD" << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "                              ";
        for(i=0;i<wordlength;i++){
            cout << word[i];
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
   }else{
         cout << "SORRY " << playername << ", " << letter << " DOES NOT EXIST IN THIS WORD" << endl << endl << endl;
         numwrongofguesses--;
        }

    if(numwrongofguesses==7){
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|                |" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }else if(numwrongofguesses==6){
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|                |" << endl;
        cout << "|                O" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }else if(numwrongofguesses==5){
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|                |" << endl;
        cout << "|                O" << endl;
        cout << "|                X" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }else if(numwrongofguesses==4){
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|                |" << endl;
        cout << "|                O" << endl;
        cout << "|               /X" << endl;
        cout << "|              /" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }else if(numwrongofguesses==3){
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|                |" << endl;
        cout << "|                O" << endl;
        cout << "|               /X\\" << endl;
        cout << "|              /   \\" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }else if(numwrongofguesses==2){
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|                |" << endl;
        cout << "|                O" << endl;
        cout << "|               /X\\" << endl;
        cout << "|              / | \\" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }else if(numwrongofguesses==1){
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|                |" << endl;
        cout << "|                O" << endl;
        cout << "|               /X\\" << endl;
        cout << "|              / | \\" << endl;
        cout << "|               /" << endl;
        cout << "|              /" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }else if(numwrongofguesses==0){
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "|                |" << endl;
        cout << "|                O" << endl;
        cout << "|               /X\\" << endl;
        cout << "|              / | \\" << endl;
        cout << "|               / \\" << endl;
        cout << "|              /   \\" << endl;
        cout << "|----------|" << endl;
        cout << "|----------|" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "                " << playername << " YOU HAVE BEEN HANGED!!!!" << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "               THE WORD WAS " << wordrevelation << endl << endl << endl;
        Gameover=true;
    }

    if(numwrongofguesses==7 || numwrongofguesses==6 || numwrongofguesses==5 ||
       numwrongofguesses==4 || numwrongofguesses==3 || numwrongofguesses==2 ||
       numwrongofguesses==1 || numwrongofguesses==0){
           cout << "                                ";
           for(i=0;i<wordlength;i++){
            cout << word[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    if(count==wordlength){
        cout << "CONGRATULATIONS " << playername << "! YOU GUESSED THE WORD!!! IT'S " << wordrevelation << endl << endl << endl;
        Gameover=true;
    }

    while(Gameover){
        cout << playername << " WOULD YOU LIKE TO PLAY AGAIN? : " << endl;
        cout << "PRESS 'y' FOR YES OR 'n' FOR NO : ";
        cin >> playagain;
        cout << endl << endl << endl;

        if(playagain=='y'){
           numwrongofguesses=8;
           count=0;
           counter=0;
           Gameover=false;

           srand(time(0));
           w=rand()%10;
           word=words[w];

           wordrevelation=word;
           wordlength=word.size();

           for(i=0;i<wordlength;i++){
           unknownword[i]=word[i];
           word[i]='-';
           }
           cout << "OKAY HERES THE HIDDEN WORD "<< word << " AND IT IS " << wordlength << " LETTERS LONG" << endl << endl << endl;
        }else{
            cout << "OKAY THEN,SEE YOU SOON." << endl;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: a `std::set<char>` springs to mind.

Comment: Create an image of hangman in `string hangman[MAX_LIVES]` and use a for loop to draw him, up to the current used lives. Then you don't need to duplicate the lines so much.

Comment: you can have a string where you add every letter tried... then you just check if the letter already exists in this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep track of letters, create a string and add the letter which the user typed . Then loop through it after each input to see if the input is already typed before. If it is ,prompt the user to enter another input. Else continue this process.

Note-I answered your question,but I did not fix several of the bugs in your code.

Comment: Sorry,suddenly lost my internet connection.This is the code i have written:                           for(x=0;x<26;x++){ if(used[x]==letter){                                            cout << "Already used that letter"}                         if(used[x]!=letter){                                           used[x]=letter; x=27;}                                                  } The only problem with this is that it only works in succession.As in if i type 'a' and then 'a' again it works,but if i type 'a' then 'b' then 'a' again it doesn't.

Comment: @nz881 ,Use another variable `counter` and use `for(x=0;x<counter;x++){ if(used
[x]==letter) cout << "Already used
that letter" /*prompt user again*/ }` and then `used[counter]=letter; counter++;` after the `for` loop

Comment: .What you said basically does the same thing. It does not work :'(

Comment: @nz881, its supposed to ! Did you initialize `counter` to 0 at the start ? And how are you prompting the user to input again? Without the code, i'll have to guess...

Comment: `int counter=0;
        for(int x =0;x<counter;x++){
            if(usedletters[x]==letter){
                cout << "Already used." << endl;
                cout << "Enter another letter: " << endl;
                cin >> letter;
            }
        }
        usedletters[counter]=letter;
        counter++;`
                                                                okay there it is.Tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @nz881 ,This should be in the beginning - `int counter=0;`  and this just after the `while(!Gameover)` - `while(1){cout << "ENTER A LETTER " << playername << " : ";         cin >> letter; for(int x =0;x<counter;x++){ if(usedletters[x] ==letter){ cout << "Already used." << endl;continue;}} break;} usedletters [counter]=letter; counter++;`

Comment: And i asked my teacher and he told me to use `cin.ignore()`.Now i have no idea how to use this as i have never used this before. I have looked it up and still don't know how to use it.I tried it on my code and it does work,but again, only in succession.

Comment: @nz881 , Try my code or put `x=0` inside the `if` in your code in your comment. Its better to use `cin.ignore()` just after using every `cin`. It will remove unwanted characters like `\n` from the input stream

Comment: well the whole `cin.ignore()` thing was useless, i got rid of it. SO yea thats taken care of. But this is still a problem man. Cant keep track of the used words. I have tried your code and it basically does the same thing i did. The thing works only in SUCCESSION. Have you tried using your code on mine? Did it work? If it did then please send it to me. Would you mind mailing it to me?

Comment: @nz881 , I figured my code had a bug. Use `while (1){cout << "ENTER A LETTER " << playername << " : "; cin >> letter; for (x =0;x<counter;x++){ if (usedletters[x] ==letter){ cout << "Already used." << endl;x=27;break;}}if(x==27) continue;break;} usedletters [counter]=letter; counter++;` and don't forget to declare `x`

Comment: Your code does not work at all this time. I declared x but it says   `error: name lookup of x changed for ISO 'for' scoping`.

Comment: @nz881 , declare `x` just after you declare `counter`. Don't declare it in the `for` loop

Comment: Okay thank you it finally works. Now you can see above that i have updated the code a little bit. As soon as the game is over the user is asked if he/she wants to play again.But for some reason my code crashes as soon as it ends. Can't find out why. Can you explain?

Comment: @nz881 , That would be another question. Post another one and accept this answer if it helped

Comment: Alright well thank you for all your help. I have posted a separate question explaining that particular problem, so if you can then please check it out.